# Bash script syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r'`

Tags: bash, stress-ng

I am writing a bash-script for stress testing on a CPU. The script should take readings of different cpu-methods while changing the number of cpu-workers. The script itself looks like this:

```
WORKERS_START=1
WORKERS_END=6
TARGET=$1

if [ -z $TARGET ]
then
    echo "Pass target cpu method"
else
    echo "Analize $TARGET"
    for i in $(seq $WORKERS_START $WORKERS_END)
    do
       echo -e "\nstart $i worker(s)\n"
       stress-ng --cpu $i --cpu-method $TARGET -t 15s --metrics | sar 1 10 -u
    done
fi
```

But when I run it on my Ubuntu server I get the following error:

```
joulin@matthewserver:~$ bash cpu_bench.sh gcd
cpu_bench.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
cpu_bench.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'pu_bench.sh: line 11: `    do
```

However, when I run it on a local machine, everything works fine. I don’t understand where the error comes from and I'll be glad if you can help me with this problem.

Comment: Your script is saved with DOS newlines

Comment: BTW, https://shellcheck.net/ is your friend -- there are some low-hanging bugs (missing quotes, etc) it'll identify. Additional to those bugs, consider `for ((i=WORKERS_START; i<WORKERS_END; i++)); do` istead of `seo`, and don't use all-caps names for your own variables -- [that namespace is used for variables meaningful to the shell and operating system](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html).